# Visual Studio 2017 not restoring packages on save

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2017

IN VS2017 I have a quick node.js "Hello world" project. The installed template for node.js includes using NPM via an included `package.json`  I am editing the package.json file to include new dependencies.  Upon saving `package.json` VS is supposed to install any new packages that are included.

I started with the project template: Other Languages\TypeScript\Node.js
[image: Project Template: Blank Node.js Web Application]

I confirmed that the option is enabled for Restoring npm packages on save of package.json

[image: Tools\Options\Projects and Solutions\Web Package Management\Package Restore]

But no matter what changes I make to package.json VS won't run npm and install the missing packages.  Also if I build or run VS won't automatically install the missing packages.  I can right click on npm and select Install Missing Packages which does work.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Did this work for you in VS2015? Specifically for Node.Js projects?

Comment: Good question since I had not tried this in VS2015.  FYI @jimmy The answer is more or less yes it works.  VS2015 does not have the same templates.  But if you create a new proejct with the Other Languages\TypeScript template then add `package.json` it will add modules when you save `package.json`.  But, it does not include them in the project by default.  You have to select the newly added module and use the context menu to Include in Project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restore on Save for NPM packages currently doesn't work in NPM projects.  I'm still tracking down the root issue, but I did come across a discussion where they (the NTVS folks) wanted to opt out of some behaviors for Web projects.

There are some context menu options on the `npm` or individual package nodes to restore/update/etc.  You could also create new keyboard shortcuts for these context menu items, but I don't know of a way to make <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> work.

I'm following up internally to revisit these decisions, but in the meantime, send in feedback so that we have some customer data to point to!

Comment: Thank you for following up.  We have been using the context menu to install missing packages.  Also running build and/or debug with build alerts you to the missing packages but does not install them.

Comment: This answer is of course correct, but it confused me.  To be clear it seems this behavior does not work in Visual Studio 2017's node.js project types (NTVS), but it does work fine in other project types AND if you use the new feature to just open a folder in Visual Studio. The behavior can be disabled using the options the OP shows.